# How can I change "Break When an Exception is Thrown" debugger behaviour from code

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I want in some part of code enable [Break When an Exception is Thrown](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d14azbfh(v=vs.110).aspx)
debugger behaviour from code, and after some part of code restore initial value.
Is it possible?

Comment: I don't think this is possible changing the debugger setting, but you can achieve this with a proper use of try catch blocks.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try do this

```
try
{
// ... <- your code here
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
}
```